# Can Cuda 10 support PyTorch 1.5+ in some way to solve: "Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled"?

Tags: pytorch

I'm getting error that says: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled. I have CUDA 10 and CUDNN 7.4 installed in my Windows 11, and I have installed torch 1.7 in the virtual env. It looks like the CUDA 10 does not support torch>1.3. But I need CUDA 10 for my other project at the same time. What could I do?

Comment: `nvidia-smi` gives the maximum supported CUDA version for your driver. It has nothing to do with the one installed.

Comment: I recommend reading all six words in that error message again. They mean you have installed a CPU only build of PyTorch. You can’t change that except by uninstalling that build and installing a different build that was compiled with GPU support.

Comment: but can I install torch 1.5+ with CUDA 10?